# "To treat someone as property" or "to treat someone as a property"?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article, zero-article

"He treats his dog as property."

or

"He treats his dog as a property."

I suspect that the former is correct, is it?

Comment: treat his dog as property is correct. You could also say "He treats his dog as a piece of property."

Comment: The first is better; the second would imply he's treating the dog as a house. I think it would sound more natural to use "his" though - "He treats the dog as his property." "He treats his wife as his property."

Comment: You could use the latter in context. Although the article would still sound odd, it wouldn't necessarily be wrong. *The tics treat his dog as a property.* In that case, the tics are small enough to actually inhabit the dog.

Answer (score 2):

*Property* can be a count noun, but in this sense it is not, so *as a property* doesn't make sense.

You could say

> He treats his dog as property.

but it is much more natural to say

> He treats his dog as his property.

Answer (score 0):

*A property* in a non-legal context would lean toward meaning "real property" - something like a house, building, or section of land.

It would be rare to treat a dog like a house or real state, so you would say "He treats his dog as property."